# MicroStrategy Query for Redshift added Limit Clause unintendedly

Tags: amazon-redshift, microstrategy

We noticed MSTR Query for Redshift was added the limit clause at the end, like 'LIMIT 600001', without our intention. Not with all the query, but costly query tends to have it automatically.

We'd like to clarify what configure makes this at Redshift or MicroStrategy.
If my memory serves me correctly, right after our migration to Redshift 8 months ago, we didn't notice such a limitation.

Any information would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the query in MSTR.
If you see LIMIT this MSTR and you should check VLBD properties.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Big brother. We asked MSTR Support and found it those unexpected limit clause is added by MicroStrategy's ODBC Driver for Redshift, according to configuration of VLBD properfy. (Normal ODBC Driver for Redshift does not add limit clause automatically though)